# How do I seed data or run scripts when installing a Salesforce package

Tags: package, salesforce

I'm developing a Salesforce package that depends on some prepopulated data to work correctly (ie: a list of countries to populate a custom setting).

1. Is there a way to prepopulate these objects at installation/upgrade time? (e.g. uploading a csv with the data I need to insert into some custom objects).
2. Is there a way to run a custom script at installation/upgrade time? (e.g. have the script update information on new fields, or adapt existing data to a modified object structure).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a new piece of functionality that is coming in the Summer '12 (API Version 25.0) release. There are two new interfaces to implement, InstallHandler and UninstallHandler, which can be setup to run on install and uninstall of a package respectively. You could implement the InstallHandler and populate the objects/custom settings in that class.

Comment: Thanks @Triangle Man. I'll wait for these features to come out and, in the meantime, provide installation instructions along with my package.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a custom settings value to know if the installation procedure was run. Then you can use your package's point of entry to check for it and do the procedure if the value indicates it needs to run. It's a little complicated if you don't have a single point of entry.